# Joomla 2.5 password reset user sync

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

We have a Joomla 2.5 website and a second site (non-Joomla) that needs to have user information synchronized. We already have implemented a user registration that syncs to the other system after the email verification link is clicked.

The issue I have now is password reset. Joomla has a nice system to allow a user to reset the password. What I need to know is once the user clicks on the email to start the reset process (reset.php), how can I grab the user information within the confirm() method? All I need is the user (email or id) so that I can pass the new encrypted password to the other system.

Any suggestions would be VERY helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In file `components\com_users\models\reset.php`, within function `processResetConfirm()` around line 227, the userid is available in `$user->id`.

```
// Get the user id.
$db->setQuery((string) $query);
$user = $db->loadObject();
```

The userid should now be found int `$user->id`

Comment: Thanks - I was actually looking in .../controllers/reset.php instead of .../models/reset.php. Thanks for the tip - I'm confident this will work.

Comment: One more note - actually, the correct insertion point is processResetComplete() just when it writes the new password to the users table. Anyway - the answer was spot on as $user is still available.